# How to include java library into shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, cygwin

I have a java class as bellow :

```
package test.shell.com;
public class RunTest { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Hello");
  }
}
```

From shell script, My code as bellow :

```
#!/bin/sh
java test.shell.com.RunTest
```

when I run the shell file via cygwin. It return the result as bellow :

[image]

So when I use a java library in java program as :

```
package test.shell.com;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class RunTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
      test.put("name","Test");
      System.out.print("Hello" + test.get("name")); 
    }
}
```

And run again shell script, it show the error message as bellow :

[image]

I know the shell script dont know about JSON library, But i dont know how to include it into shell script. Please help...

Comment: You need to make a jar with all imported libraries. [About jar files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)

Comment: It's not the shell script that doesn't know about the library, it's the program itself. Either it doesn't exist on your system or you need to specify the correct classpath

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko  can you description more detail about make a jar with all imported lib?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the paths of jars to a param , and use “java -classpath” command to run it.

for example : CLASSPATH=yourownjar.jar:xxx.jar:/xx/xx/xxx1.jar:"$CLASSPATH"  (yourownjar and the jdk classpath config should also be included in this param)

And then use java -classpath to run:

java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} xx.Main

Comment: still not working, When i add classpath, it show this error **Error: main class test.shell.com.RunTest could not be found or could not be loaded
**

Comment: @HocN year, I forgot, your own jar should also be included in the classpath.

Comment: @MaxllowFox I added my jar file like : 
`CLASSPATH=/test/shell/com/test.jar:/test/shell/com/json-simple-1.1.jar
java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} test.shell.com.RunTest` But it still show old error.

Comment: @HocN CLASSPATH=/test/shell/com/test.jar:/test/shell/com/json-simp‌​le-1.1.jar:"$CLASSPATH",   the origin classpath in the machine env should also be included

Comment: @MaxllowFox I added all thing like CLASSPATH=/test/shell/com/test.jar:/test/shell/com/json-simp‌​‌​le-1.1.jar:"$CLASS‌​PATH" But it still show that error :((

Comment: @HocN try echo $CLA‌​SS‌​PATH  before run java command, see if the classpath is right